# Windows Server 2012 after power outage

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, electrical-power, outage

Had a power outage, server restarted normally.
Server is a database server for a hotel, which is connected to an ISP with optic fibre.
On the restart, network went public, instead of the default private network. Had to tear down the firewall. Could not ping outside nor inside.

Any idea how I could avoid this, during a next power outage?
Thanks in advance, hope I gave enough information.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if DNS lookups fail. For example when both of your DCs/DNS servers are rebooting because of the power outage. Don't know your infrastructure but it is a good idea to implement startup delays for VMs for example (if your server is a VM).

Comment: The thing is, we(in the firm) have a startup delay, which is why we are boggled with this issue.
We have a Dell server with windows 2012 server on, no VM's.

Comment: I would try to set the `Network Location Awareness` service to delayed start and/or configure the firewall for all profiles. This is odd but the whole NLA thing is a mess and not useful IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We'll see how things go till next power outage.